# Is there a way to purchase the official Lion release when the Gold Master was previously installed?

Tags: upgrade, mac-appstore, macos

Is there a way to install the official release when you installed the Gold Master version? I can't purchase it from the app store because it think I have the app already intalled...

I wonder how you can purchase/install lion on x machines since your appstore login can be used at home, at works, etc...

Comment: Sadly the pre-requirements for Lion don't include beta versions of Lion - just consumer versions of Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

http://handpickedpixels.com/app-store-refuses-lion-download/

Easy

Comment: Holding down the option key while pressing install, doesn't work for me. I'm on Mac OS X 10.7 Build 11A494a.

Comment: Aha. It does work. But you must hold down the option key for a really long time. Start holding it down before you start the MacAppStore. And release the option key after you press install. This did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Word on the street](http://twitter.com/siegel/status/93689935869116416) is it's not necessary in the short term as build 11A494 once installed is the same as 11A511 (& same as the final GM seed).

If you still want to do something today (and don't want to hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down when clicking purchase to bypass the App Store check) - I would install Snow Leopard to a spare partition or USB drive and do the purchase / download from there.

At that point, you can erase / restore / install as desired. Worst case, you'll have to wait for instructions or migrate your GM system to a fresh new install.

In the mean time - [we can pick apart the manifest and pre-flight script for Lion](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/1924/get-lion) ;-)

Comment: Given Apple's usual response times, by the time all this was done Apple would've told you how to upgrade :)

Comment: Sadly, I've done it so many times, a clean stock SL install is something I have a DMG of and just drop it on a partition in 10 minutes.

Comment: There is a big difference between the two versions if you are a Mac developer. In order for a developer to submit apps for the MacAppStore, the developer must not run the 11A494a version. He must install the Lion via the MacAppstore otherwise validating in Xcode will complain about SDK issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to upgrade. The GM Seed version is the same as what's on the Mac App Store today.

Comment: Does this mean that we'll have free upgrades once Apple comes out with 10.7.1 and 10.7.2?

Comment: It should. Just log in with the credentials you used to download Lion from the App store.

Comment: If you are a Mac developer then you must upgrade, otherwise you cannot submit your app to the MacAppStore. Xcode is complaining about SDK issues when I try to submit.

Comment: If it is complaining about SDK issues then it's not the OS, it is the version of Xcode you are running.